# Condition with '||' (OR) returns true always

Tags: apex, conditional

Why is it always returning TRUE in the given logic?

```
List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Account.Id, Email, FirstName, LastName,Phone FROM Contact where AccountId=: accId];

for(Contact c : cons) 
{
    if(c.Email == null || c.phone == null) {
        system.debug(c.Email == null || c.phone == null); // return true all 3 records
     } 
}
```

Or tried with `isEmpty`

```
if(String.isEmpty(c.Email) || String.isEmpty(c.Phone)) {
    system.debug('contact : '+c);
}
```

I have total of three records in the Contact object and one of the record I have phone number entered so logically I should get only two records in the system.debug but instead getting all three records, even though I have phone number on one of the Contact record

Comment: I gave this -1 for lack of research.

Comment: I think the logic gate you're looking for is `XOR` (Exclusive `OR`).  `XOR` gates return `true` if and only if *exactly one* of the operands is `true`.  Salesforce (and some other languages) use the `^` operator for `XOR`.  So you can do `String.isEmpty(c.Email) ^ String.isEmpty(c.Phone)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That clause returns true if *any* of the fields are `null`. Here's a simple truth table for that statement:

```
record.Email == null || record.Phone == null

Email Null?  |  Phone Null?  |  Either Null?
--------------------------------------------------
true         |  true         |  true
true         |  false        |  true
false        |  true         |  true
false        |  false        |  false
```

Or, perhaps easier to wrap your head around:

```
Contact eitherNull1 = new Contact(Phone=null, Email=null);
Contact eitherNull2 = new Contact(Phone='1234567890', Email=null);
Contact eitherNull3 = new Contact(Phone=null, Email='test@example.com');

Contact neitherNull = new Contact(Phone='1234567890', Email='test@example.com');
```

Only the last record there will return `false`.

---

If you only want to look at records where *all* the fields are `null`, you need to use AND (`&&`) instead.

```
record.Email == null && record.Phone == null

Email Null?  |  Phone Null?  |  Both Null?
--------------------------------------------------
true         |  true         |  true
true         |  false        |  false
false        |  true         |  false
false        |  false        |  false
```

Which can also be seen as:

```
Contact bothNull = new Contact(Phone=null, Email=null);

Contact eitherNotNull1 = new Contact(Phone='1234567890', Email=null);
Contact eitherNotNull2 = new Contact(Phone=null, Email='test@example.com');    
Contact eitherNotNull3 = new Contact(Phone='1234567890', Email='test@example.com');
```

Comment: I was about to start typing saying that, yeah, this is exactly how logical OR is supposed to work.

Comment: @Adrian, Yes I see the truth table okay so I was thinking if any one of the field is has value it should return false;

Comment: @Nick That would be `&&` and the right hand column would read `Both Null?`

Comment: I understand `&&`  logical AND operator (&&) returns the boolean value true if both operands are true and returns false otherwise, but I'm after if any of one operands are true then should get the false in context with the above logic.

Comment: @Nick You're getting yourself confused. Please illustrate in your Original Post with one `Contact` record for each combination and your expected evaluation.